# Why Solve works but FindRoot needs precision. How to fix?

Tags: equation-solving

So how do I change the machine precision so that FindRoot works? I am unsure what to put into the program to fix. I tried setting the precision and that did not seem to work for me.

```
In[1304]:= Clear[kay2]
a = -(767.6168675560641/(
   2034.4015218904594 + 1098.5256888360263/kay2)) + 
  177571.25454917824/(8137.606087561838 + 4394.102755344105/kay2)
b = -(767.6168675560641/(
    2034.4015218904594 + 1098.5256888360263/kay2)) + 
   177571.25454917824/(8137.606087561838 + 4394.102755344105/kay2) == 
  22.4
NIFinal2 = 
 kay2 /. FindRoot[a == 22.4, {kay2, 2}, AccuracyGoal -> 200, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 200]
Solve[b, kay2]


Out[1305]= -(767.617/(2034.4 + 1098.53/kay2)) + 177571./(
 8137.61 + 4394.1/kay2)

Out[1306]= -(767.617/(2034.4 + 1098.53/kay2)) + 177571./(
  8137.61 + 4394.1/kay2) == 22.4

During evaluation of In[1304]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

Out[1307]= 1.21088*10^6

During evaluation of In[1304]:= Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.

Out[1308]= {{kay2 -> -12.6488}}
```

K THANX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either increase the precision of your input or make it exact, use the [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision) option, and pick a better start value:

```
FindRoot[
    Rationalize[a==22.4, 0], (* exact equation *)
    {kay2, -12}, (* better start value *)
    WorkingPrecision -> 150, (* include WorkingPrecision option *)
    AccuracyGoal -> 100,
    PrecisionGoal -> 100
]
```

> {kay2 -> -12.6488173748687333535160106718096642152404100487827781781965021403330127347285113911677328711414745534828594373909418395952182263537957980538822675461}

You could also do the same thing with [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve):

```
kay2 /. First @ Solve[Rationalize[b,0], kay2]
N[%, 100]
```

> -(72004542002168455901234846000/5692590846100005709933641061)
>
> -12.64881737486873335351601067180966421524041004878277817819650214033301273472851139116773287114147455

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[kay2]

a = -(767.6168675560641/(2034.4015218904594 + 1098.5256888360263/kay2)) + 
     177571.25454917824/(8137.606087561838 + 4394.102755344105/kay2) // 
    Rationalize[#, 0] & // Simplify;

b = a == 22.4 // Rationalize // Simplify;
```

When using [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) it is useful to [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) the function to get a reasonable initial estimate.

```
Plot[{a, 22.4}, {kay2, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> {15, 30}]
```

[image]

```
NIFinal2 = kay2 /. FindRoot[a == 224/10, {kay2, -10}]

(* -12.6488 *)

kay2 /. Solve[b, kay2][[1]] // N

(* -12.6488 *)
```